# Он уже нежив / не жив

Tags: орфография

Как правильно? По идее, надо, т. к. имеется в виду *мёртв*, писать же *нежив*, но...

> Он уже нежив / не жив.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:  *Он уже **не жив**.*

Отрицание признака: **в данный момент** уже не жив. Значение времени подчеркивает наречие ***уже***.

**Грамматика кратких прилагательных**

В краткой форме заложена большая по сравнению с полной формой возможность указывать на **ПЕРЕМЕННЫЙ**, относительный характер данного признака для данного субъекта, предмета. Поэтому если прилагательное называет такой признак, который является временным для предмета или может количественно меняться внутри него, более употребительна краткая форма.

**Практика письма:** **[Нацкорпус](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CjsqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCGAoWChQKA3JlcRINCgvQvdC1INC20LjQsjAB)**

**Обычно раздельное написание**

(1) Александр Солженицын. Матренин двор (1960).
За одиннадцать послевоенных лет решила и Матрена сама, что он **не жив.**

Значение **отрицания:** думала, что жив, но поняла, что это не так.

(2) Четыре вечера (2004) // «Театральная жизнь», 23.02.2004.
Нет, он давно **уже не жив**, Николай Алексеевич Иванов, потому что надорвался, как мужик, для куража взваливший на плечи два огромных мешка.

Здесь **переносное** значение, отрицание дух признаков: не живой и не мертвый, как личность уже не существует.

(3) Сказка о царевиче Артобазе Хиразовиче — сильном, могучем богатыре (1794-1795).
И так спустили они в тот столб по стреле, и Еруслан-царевич сказал Ивану-нянькину сыну: «Слушай, брат, ежели ты приедешь прежде к этому столбу и стрела моя будет красна, то знай, что я **уже не жив...**

Здесь  говорится **о будущем времени:** красная стрела покажет, что уже не жив.

**Слитное написание** только в одном примере: нЕжив (=мертв)

П. И. Мельников-Печерский. В лесах. Книга первая (1871-1874)
Вытерпел старец — слова не проронил, только молитву читал, как они его мучили. За́мертво бросили в чулан, думали, **неЕжив**. Но помиловал бог — отдышался.

Comment: То есть *нежив* — это тоже корректно?

Comment: Да, корректно в значении "мертв", но используется редко. В орфографическом словаре указана полная форма неживой, от нее можно образовать краткую форму.  Обычно применяется полная форма  https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=Cj4qGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCGwoZChcKA3JlcRIQCg7QvdC10LbQuNCy0L7QuTAB